# How would I change the selected tab in onBackStackChanged?

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

When the back button is clicked, the screen displays the previous fragment, but the selected tab in the action bar doesn't change, so I would probably have to set the selected fragment in onBackStackChanged right?

However, it's not working, when I switch to a different tab, the app freezes.
It seems that it is being selected multiple times simultaneously because when I logged it, the backstack is changed very quickly multiple times.

I've figured out why it's freezing. When I set the selected navigation item, it calls onTabSelected() again which in turn calls on backStackChanged which in turn repeats. So how would I select which tab to underline, without having to reselect the tab?

```
@Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){



        FragmentManager manage = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manage.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if(actionBar.getSelectedTab().equals(tabRed))
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
                if(actionBar.getSelectedTab().equals(tabBlue))
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
                if(actionBar.getSelectedTab().equals(tabMatches))
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);


            }
        });



        if(tab.equals(tabComp))
        {
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.animation_fragment_out, R.anim.animation_fragment_switch);

            trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(android.R.id.content, teamsFrag);


        trans.addToBackStack(null);
        trans.commit();

        }
else if(tab.equals(tabRed))
        {


            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.animation_fragment_out, R.anim.animation_fragment_switch);

            trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(android.R.id.content, redScorerFrag);



        trans.addToBackStack(null);
        trans.commit();
            curTab = tabRed;

        }
```